# Visual Studio 2012 Can't load projects after installing Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, updates

I am on Windows 8, updated my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to Update 3 recently. Immediately after successful update, I tried loading the project i was working on (I so wish I had not updated in between the on going project) now it gives me the error which says `load faied` in front of all projects in the solution.

I tried to resolve error by right clicking on solution, but it gives me error `All property accessors must be methods.` in an error dialog box. Same error comes when i try to make new project as well.

Any one know any work around?

Edit: I have been going through options online, I think rolling back to previous update will solve the problem. Anyone knows any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was, but after spending considerable amount of time, I had to go back to previous version and my projects were set again. For anyone with same problem, here's how to do it:

Go to `Control Panel -> Programs -> View Installed Updates` and uninstall the Update 3 under Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 category. U have to repair visual studio after that. And it will be set!